# How to create and format a partition using a Bash script?

Tags: bash, partitioning, ntfs, fdisk

Is there any way to create and format a partition using a Bash script?

I think it can be done with [`fdisk`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fdisk.8.html) but I don't know how to feed commands from the Bash script into the `fdisk` shell and then exit the `fdisk` shell.

I'd like to create a partition then format it to NTFS from within Bash.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Similar to the previous suggestions, piping commands to fidsk,  I've found this approach useful to leave details for subsequent maintainers. The sed bits strip off all the comments before fdisk gets the input.

```
# to create the partitions programatically (rather than manually)
# we're going to simulate the manual input to fdisk
# The sed script strips off all the comments so that we can 
# document what we're doing in-line with the actual commands
# Note that a blank line (commented as "defualt" will send a empty
# line terminated with a newline to take the fdisk default.
sed -e 's/\s*\([\+0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/' << EOF | fdisk ${TGTDEV}
  o # clear the in memory partition table
  n # new partition
  p # primary partition
  1 # partition number 1
    # default - start at beginning of disk 
  +100M # 100 MB boot parttion
  n # new partition
  p # primary partition
  2 # partion number 2
    # default, start immediately after preceding partition
    # default, extend partition to end of disk
  a # make a partition bootable
  1 # bootable partition is partition 1 -- /dev/sda1
  p # print the in-memory partition table
  w # write the partition table
  q # and we're done
EOF
```

Comment: I completely agree. Document your work for others to read.

Comment: Note you have to have a leading tab on each line.

Comment: Would you mind placing a **big warning** that a tab is required on each command character line as @Stu mentioned? I had to debug for a while just because copy-and-paste ignores tabs and replaces them with spaces, thus regex does not match with command lines.

Comment: Instead of a warning about tabs, I've modified the sed to discard leading whitespace (not just tabs) and not expect a tab after the fdisk commands. This should cut and paste better. @ceremcem - good feedback and sorry to caused you any debug time.

Comment: `sfdisk` is more automation friendly than `fdisk`

Comment: I used this with success, right up until I happened to place a partition right where one already was, and fdisk wanted confirmation? Then I started using sfdisk which is just way easier and never asks for confirmation. Thanks to Ciro Santilli below.

Comment: I know that this is a pretty old question, but can someone tell me whether or not this program will work? Will it open fdisk for the user to run?

Answer (score 116):

[**sfdisk**](https://man.archlinux.org/man/sfdisk.8)

`sfdisk` is a Scripted version of `fdisk`.

[It is part of `util-linux`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/disk-utils?h=stable/v2.27), just like `fdisk`, so availability should be the same.

A partition table with a single partition that takes the whole disk can be
created with:

```
echo 'type=83' | sudo sfdisk /dev/sdX
```

and more complex partition tables are explained below.

To generate an example script, get the setup of one of your disks:

```
sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > sda.sfdisk
```

Sample output on my Lenovo T430 Windows 7 / Ubuntu dual boot:

```
label: dos
label-id: 0x7ddcbf7d
device: /dev/sda
unit: sectors

/dev/sda1 : start=        2048, size=     3072000, type=7, bootable
/dev/sda2 : start=     3074048, size=   195430105, type=7
/dev/sda3 : start=   948099072, size=    28672000, type=7
/dev/sda4 : start=   198504446, size=   749594626, type=5
/dev/sda5 : start=   198504448, size=   618891264, type=83
/dev/sda6 : start=   940277760, size=     7821312, type=82
/dev/sda7 : start=   817397760, size=    61437952, type=83
/dev/sda8 : start=   878837760, size=    61437500, type=83
```

Once you have the script saved to a file, you can apply it to `sdX` with:

```
sudo sfdisk /dev/sdX < sda.sfdisk
```

For `sfdisk` input, you can just omit the device names, and use lines of type:

```
start=        2048, size=     3072000, type=7, bootable
```

They are just ignored if present, and the device name is taken from the command line argument.

Some explanations:

- header lines: all optional:

  - `label`: type of partition table. [`dos` (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) is the old and widely supported one, [`gpt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) the new shiny thing.
  - `unit`: only `sector` is supported. 1 sector usually equals 512 bytes. Find with `cat /sys/block/sda/queue/hw_sector_size`. See also: [Finding the sector size of a partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/finding-the-sector-size-of-a-partition)
  - `device`: informative only I think
- partition lines:

  - `start`: offset inside the disk at which the partition starts.

    `start` has very good defaults, and can often be omitted:

    - on the first line, `start` is 2048, i.e. 1Mb (2048 + 512), which is a sane default for disk compatibility
    - further `start` entries default to the first unallocated position
  - `size`: `man sfdisk` says: `The default value of size indicates "as much as possible"`. So to fill the disk with a single partition use: `/dev/sda : start=2048, type=83`
  - `type`: magic byte stored on the boot sector for each [partition entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#PTE). Possible values here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type On this example we observe:

    - `7` (`sda1`, `2` and `3`): filesystems that Windows supports. Preinstalled Windows stuff and Lenovo recovery partitions. `sudo blkid` labels help identify them.
    - `5` (`sda4`): extended primary partition, which will contain other logical partitions (because we can only have 4 primary partitions with MBR)
    - `83`(`sda5`, `7`, and `8`): partitions which Linux supports. For me one `home`, and two roots with different Ubuntu versions
    - `82` (`sd6`): swap

`fdisk` can also read `sfdisk` scripts with the `I` command, which "sources" them during an interactive `fdisk` session, allowing you further customization before writing the partition.

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, `sfdisk` 2.27.1.

**Format and populate the partitions an image file without `sudo`**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949169/how-to-create-a-multi-partition-sd-disk-image-without-root-privileges/52850819#52850819) is a good way to learn to use `sfdisk` without blowing up your hard disks.

Comment: OMG this is amazing. I've used fdisk before but if you accidentally land exactly where there is already a partition it will want verification from the user that it doesn't usually require, which sucks. sfdisk is wonderful, thank you!

Comment: Note that GPT uses GUIDs for partition types instead of hex codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs

Comment: I got an error "Failed to add #1 partition: Invalid argument" it's a brand RIAD5 4.4TB disk.  I did `echo 'type=83' | sfdisk /dev/sdb`  What could be the reason?

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi sorry, not sure, let me know if you manage to fix it. What's your OS name and version BTW?

Comment: very easy to get disaster. I would prefer some declarative language to do this. All fdisk never really mk the file system, which is another inconvenience.

Answer (score 76):

`fdisk` reads from *stdin* so you just need to feed it the appropriate commands.  For example, the following clears the partition table, if there is one, and makes a new one that has a single partition that is the; entire disk:

```
(
echo o # Create a new empty DOS partition table
echo n # Add a new partition
echo p # Primary partition
echo 1 # Partition number
echo   # First sector (Accept default: 1)
echo   # Last sector (Accept default: varies)
echo w # Write changes
) | sudo fdisk
```

I recommend you do the task you want, recording what you type so you can reproduce it.

Comment: While a bit more verbose with the echo commands than the accepted answer, this seems much less magical and obfuscated.

Comment: I personally would suggest the use of `printf` instead of `echo` just to be in the habit of using something that behaves consistently across systems.

Comment: @vastlysuperiorman I don't think that printf would work as in-place replacement for echo as it doesn't insert the line break

Comment: @Andrey you are correct. The equivalent of `echo o` here would be `printf "o\n"` which looks less clean. I personally prefer printf because it feels more intentional, but echo is a totally valid solution.

Comment: Why `( ) |` instead of `{ } |`? Are they both ok, or subshell is required?

Comment: I suppose you could use `{}` but you would have to terminate each command with `;` in that case.

Answer (score 48):

You can do it with just a couple of commands, use intros **\n** instead of multiple echos.

```
echo -e "o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw" | fdisk /dev/sda
```

Comment: This is more terse than the others, but unfortunately seems to only work with bash.

Comment: It's working with ash/busybox too.

Comment: There are, however, problems with dash :-/

Comment: Is another `\n` needed after the `w`?

Comment: This works, but is horrible :-)

Comment: @ElgsQianChen: no, because `echo` automatically terminates the line with a newline (unless `-n` option is used)

Comment: would `printf` work better?  i vaguely remember seeing somewhere that printf is the preferred method for some types of output.  my understanding is there are 2 versions of `echo`: one in the shell; one as a command line version (i.e. stored in /bin/ in my linux dist)

Comment: I had to add another `\n`, so this worked for me: `echo -e "o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw" | fdisk /dev/sdb`

Answer (score 14):

Create a new disklabel type gpt:

`sudo /sbin/parted /dev/xvdf mklabel gpt --script`

Partition the disk:

`sudo /sbin/parted /dev/xvdf mkpart primary 0% 100% --script`

Comment: Thank you, this is the only clean solution for me cause it dosn't include piping some kind of "space opera.docx" to fdisk.

Comment: you have to call separated commands to mk file system, which is not very nice

Answer (score 10):

You can script `fdisk`.

```
(echo n; echo p; echo 1; echo 1; echo 200; echo w) | fdisk /dev/sdc
```

That creates a 200 MB  partition on `/dev/sdc`

Comment: Elegant answer!

Answer (score 7):

Piping commands to fdisk works well as explained by other people, but this way a bit more elegant and readable:

```
fdisk /dev/sdc <<EOF
n
p
1


w
EOF
```

Piping from a (temporary) file also works:

```
fdisk /dev/sdc < /tmp/fdisk.cmds
```

Comment: This one gets my vote. It's clean and isn't polluted with a running commentary.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf 'o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw' | fdisk /dev/sda
```

Comment: A common mistake new users make is to answer without details of how to actually resolves the issue. Answers should be detailed and include references, as needed. Please take a few minutes to edit your answer to include details of why your answer is valid. If you need some help, read [How do I write a good answer?](//superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). Also, please realize you have posted an answer to a very old questions which has an accepted answer. Although there is noting wrong with doing so, you may not get a response from the OP.

Comment: Is this different from: http://superuser.com/a/739586/128124 ?

Answer (score 0):

The script uses **fdisk** to create partitons based on other people answers.

Change the following in the script:

**NUM_PARTITIONS**=5

**PARTITION_SIZE**="+10G"

Example usage is given after the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "input the device"
  exit
fi

NUM_PARTITIONS=5
PARTITION_SIZE="+10G"    

SED_STRING="o"
TAIL="p
w
q
"

NEW_LINE="
"
LETTER_n="n"
EXTENDED_PART_NUM=4
TGTDEV=$1

SED_STRING="$SED_STRING$NEW_LINE"
for i in $(seq $NUM_PARTITIONS)
do
  if [ $i -lt $EXTENDED_PART_NUM ]
  then
    SED_STRING="$SED_STRING$LETTER_n$NEW_LINE$NEW_LINE$NEW_LINE$NEW_LINE$PARTITION_SIZE$NEW_LINE"
  fi
  if [ $i -eq $EXTENDED_PART_NUM ]
  then
    SED_STRING="$SED_STRING$LETTER_n$NEW_LINE$NEW_LINE$NEW_LINE$NEW_LINE"
    SED_STRING="$SED_STRING$LETTER_n$NEW_LINE$NEW_LINE$PARTITION_SIZE$NEW_LINE"
  fi
  if [ $i -gt $EXTENDED_PART_NUM ]
  then
    SED_STRING="$SED_STRING$LETTER_n$NEW_LINE$NEW_LINE$PARTITION_SIZE$NEW_LINE"
  fi
done
SED_STRING="$SED_STRING$TAIL"

sed -e 's/\s*\([\+0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/' << EOF | fdisk ${TGTDEV}
  $SED_STRING
EOF
```

run with:

**sudo sh mk_partition.sh /dev/sdxxx**

Answer (score 0):

Not that anyone's asking but I thought I will just share it here since I bumped into it. I tried applying the following sfdisk command on Centos 7:

> echo 'type=83' | sudo sfdisk /dev/xvdb

But received the following response:

```
Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ...
OK

Disk /dev/xvdb: 1958 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
sfdisk:  /dev/xvdb: unrecognized partition table type

Old situation:
sfdisk: No partitions found

sfdisk: trailing junk after number

sfdisk: bad input
```

Finally this is what worked for me:

```
sfdisk -f -uS -D /dev/xvdb << EOF
2048,,83,*
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working script.
In the working dir, the overlay dir contains the file image and the mnt dir is used to temporarily mount the image.

```
#!/bin/sh
#

filebase=Anx4Init

rm -f $filebase.zip

dd if=/dev/zero of=$filebase.img bs=64M count=1

(
echo n # Add a new partition
echo p # Primary partition
echo 1 # Partition number
echo   # First sector (Accept default: 1)
echo   # Last sector (Accept default: varies)
echo t # Partition type
echo 6 # FAT16
echo a # bootable
echo w # Write changes
) | sudo fdisk $filebase.img

sudo losetup -P /dev/loop777 $filebase.img
sudo mkfs.fat -F 16 -n Anx4Init /dev/loop777p1
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/loop777p1 mnt
sudo cp -R overlay/* mnt

sudo umount mnt
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop777

zip $filebase.zip $filebase.img

rm -f $filebase.img
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/sh
hdd="/dev/hda /dev/hdb /dev/hdc"
for i in $hdd;do
echo "n
p
1


w
"|fdisk $i;mkfs.ext3 "$i1";done
```

You can use this script. Just make sure you define your own partitions where `hdd` is defined. There are 2 blank spaces between `1` and `w`; they need to be there for taking default values.